# Nestjs/swagger: how to document the JWT payload?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I have a controller's `login()` method that can return either `200 OK` with JWT token fitted with `Session` payload or `451 Unavailable due to legal reasons` with JWT token fitted with AcceptTerms payload if user trying to log in needs to agree to new version of terms&conditions.

```ts
@Nest.Post("login")
@ApiOperation({ title: 'Log in the user given email and password',  operationId: 'userLogin'})
@Nest.UseFilters(UnavailableLegalReasonsExceptionFilter)
@ApiResponse({ status: HttpStatus.OK, description: "User was properly logged in", type: JwtToken})
@ApiResponse({ status: 451, description: "User haven't confirmed the latest version of Terms & Conditions", type: JwtToken})
async login(@Nest.Body() body: DTOs.LoginDto): Promise<JwtToken> {
    ...
}
```

Now, I'd like to document it with Swagger. `JwtToken` is defined as:

```ts
export class JwtToken {
    @ApiModelProperty({enum: TOKEN})
    type: TOKEN;

    @ApiModelProperty({description: "Number of seconds"})
    expiresIn: number;

    @ApiModelProperty({ description: "Token", example: "eyJhb ... wWFQ"})
    accessToken: string;
}
```

and `TOKEN`:

```ts
export enum TOKEN {
    AcceptTerms = "AcceptTerms",
    Session = "Session"
}
```

But writing that `login()` returns just a `JwtToken` is confusing as in case of `200` the `type` is `Session` and in case of `451` it is `AcceptTerms`. The payloads differ significantly too:

```ts
export class JwtPayload {
  @ApiModelProperty({enum: TOKEN, description: "Token type"})
  type: TOKEN;

  @ApiModelProperty()
  issuedAt: number;
}

export class LoginJwtPayload extends JwtPayload {
  @ApiModelProperty()
  name: string;

  @ApiModelProperty({description: "T&C version accepted"})
  tncAccepted: number;
}

export class AcceptTermsJwtPayload extends JwtPayload {
  @ApiModelProperty({format: "email"})
  email: string;
}
```

`200`'s token uses `LoginJwtPayload` payload and `451`'s uses `AcceptTermsJwtPayload`.

How to document it using Nest's SwaggerModule?

Comment: Can you not use `LoginJwtPayload` for `200` and `AcceptTermsJwtPayload` for `451`?

Comment: No, `JwtToken` that `login()` returns is an object that holds string with token type, number of seconds to expiration and long string of characters that are encoded token. `*JwtPayload` are objects that are available once the token gets decoded later. Still, it would be great to document at `login()` what you get once you decode that token.

Comment: Best case is to use an Interceptor for this use-case. Or you can just append TokenType to the login() return type